# Hide approved products in App Store App page

Tags: swift, app-store-connect, storekit

When someone search or land in my App Store app page they can see in the description a list of the approved products my app have [(See the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfyc4.jpg). Can I hide some products? I don't want to cancel those products because that will cause ending my current customers subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to hide in-app purchases from that list. You can only promote specific in-app purchases, which might draw the user's attention to them, but that's more our a walk-around then solution: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/promoting-in-app-purchases/

Comment: but i have seen, for example, apps like tinder that only shows a list of about 10 items in their app page, but in the app itselfs it offers more products (not listed in the App store page) based on the user behavior inside the app, products like "50%off  one time offer".

Comment: Yes, this will probably be best on the "popularity" of in-app purchases. The more you have, the higher the chance is that your "standard" in-app purchases are displayed there.